# How to achieve in styles or css the layout of Whatsapp ChatBubble specifically on their timestamp

Tags: css, react-native

[image]

Sorry for not showing any code. I want to achieve the timestamp style of **Whatsapp** chatbubble in **React Native**.

As you can see in the first two messages since they are not that long the timestamp at the end sticks along with the message its just a little bit lowered.

But the last two messages timestamp is below the chat text since the text are now longer.

I tried to achieve this using Flexbox and putting a `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on the chat bubble and `alignSelf: 'flex-end`' on the timestamp text but it didn't do the job.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just made the container of the msg and the timestamp `inline-block`.
Something like this:

```css
.container {
  background-color:#666;
  width:400px;
  text-align:right;
  padding:20px;
}
.chat {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;;
  background-color:lime;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
span {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
.time {
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-top:4px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-chat">
    <div class="chat">
      <span>this is the msg</span>
      <span class="time">time</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-chat">
    <div class="chat">
      <span>this is the msg longer</span>
      <span class="time">time</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-chat">
    <div class="chat">
      <span>this is the msg much, much longer</span>
      <span class="time">time</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-chat">
    <div class="chat">
      <span>this is the msg much, much, much, much, much longer</span>
      <span class="time">time</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-chat">
    <div class="chat">
      <span>this is the msg much, much, much, much, much, much, much, much longer</span>
      <span class="time">time</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```